# Añadir colaborador en proyecto GitHub después de un Pull Request

Tags: git, github

Tengo un proyecto alojado en GitHub. Hace unos días recibí un pull request de alguien que había hecho un fork del proyecto. Después de verificar y aprobar los cambios fusioné el pull request y los cambios se añadieron correctamente.

Lo que no entiendo es por qué después de incorporar los cambios figuro yo como único colaborador en el proyecto e incluso en el archivo que fue modificado. Yo mismo he propuesto algún cambio en otro proyecto y al ser aprobado automáticamente (o eso creo) he sido añadido como colaborador.

He estado mirando en los ajustes del proyecto en GitHub y no veo la manera de incorporar a un colaborador si no se hace manualmente.

La pregunta es: ¿Se pueden incorporar colaboradores de forma automática después de aprobar un pull request o esto se debe hacer manualmente?

Comment: Hasta donde tengo entendido, el hecho de que a uno le aprueben el PR no quiere decir que deba/pueda ser aceptado automáticamente como contributor. Creo que son cosas distintas y separadas. https://help.github.com/es/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-requests

Comment: Es lo que intento que me aseguren. Para que su cambio se viera reflejado (por ej. que al ver el archivo que el ha modificado apareciésemos tanto él como yo como colaboradores), lo primero que yo debería haber hecho ANTES de aceptar el PR, ¿es haberlo añadido como colaborador? ¿Ésa es la única forma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es necesario darle permisos a un tercero para que pueda forkear y luego abrir un PR a tu proyecto open source. Eso sólo se hace si quieres delegarle la potestad de hacer o aprobar cambios sin tu aprobación.

Formalmente, si se cumplen las condiciones, él sí debiera aparecer como colaborador, pero me da la impresión de que hizo el commit firmando con un correo que no es el de su cuenta github

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fíjate que no lo firmó como [t1t0n](https://github.com/t1t0n). Por lo mismo, github no tiene cómo saber quién es y no constituye un contributor.

Fíjate en los commits de tu proyecto:

```
commit 8d608d909cb32fa17987afa1983c21a731c82f6d
Author: Davit Kobaladze <dkobaladze@xxxxxxxx.com> <-- no es su mail github
Date:   Fri Nov 8 11:37:29 2019 +0400

added support for diplomatic document type (DP).

commit 39dfea973387d8e326cc6ea90f34785c61b16abc
Author: Arg0s1080 <ivan.rincon76@xxxxx.com>
Date:   Mon Aug 5 14:07:06 2019 +0200

del useless code
```

En tanto sus commits en otro repo figuran con

```
commit 46164b5735d2b5a1c160decdfdd1701d64753913 (tag: v1.0.0)
Author: Davit Kobaladze <davitkobaladze3@xxxx.com>
Date:   Sun Aug 18 21:13:04 2019 +0400

first commit of training code and examples of inference.
```

La solución es añadir un archivo `.mailmap` para ayudar a github (a git en general) a entender quién es quién. Le tomará a github entre 24 y 36 horas en actualizar tus contributors con el autor mapeado.

https://github.com/Arg0s1080/mrz/pull/9

Ya se ve en el preview al menos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te faltó añadirte a ti mismo. Mañana lo haré yo. Muchísimas gracias

Comment: Yo firmé con mi usuario igual como has hecho tú, en realidad sólo hay que mapearlo a él.

Comment: Bueno, ya que me incluiste a mí, creo que lo justo es que también estés incluido.

Comment: Pero bastaba que el mailmap tuviera a kobaladze, nosotros firmamos con el usuario real

Answer (score 0):

A un colaborador le puedes añadir manualmente: [Invitar a colaborador](https://help.github.com/es/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository) y tendrá una serie de privilegios sobre el repositorio/proyecto.

Si un usuario hace un PR también esta colaborando, aportando código, pero no tiene la necesidad de hacer modificaciones, por ejemplo, en la configuración del repositorio.

Comment: Sí, entiendo que desde los ajustes del proyecto se pueden añadir colaboradores. Mi problema está en tu 2º párrafo. Si un usuario hace un PR esta colaborando, pero como comentaba en la pregunta. Un usuario ha hecho un PR que he incorporado al proyecto. Pero tanto en el archivo que él ha modificado como en los datos generales del proyecto aparezco yo como único colaborador. Yo he hecho PR y sí aparezco como colaborador. Mi duda está en que si en esos casos el mantenedor del repo me añadió 1º como colaborador y luego aceptó el PR o es algo que por alguna razón mi repo no hace de forma automática.

Comment: He hecho varios PR en repositorios que no era colaborador. En el momento en que el propietario acepta el PR, mi usuario aparece como colaborador en cada uno de los ficheros que modificaba mi PR. Entiendo que es automático.
Se me ocurre que al aceptar el PR exista algún tipo de opción, que no reconozca al colaborador, pero sería algo raro raro...

Comment: Podría ser... Algo que hice o dejé de hacer durante la aprobación del PR. Fue todo hecho vía navegador, así que puede que se me pasara algo.